Why is randomness required in the Monte Carlo Estimation of $\pi$?
A classical demonstration for a Monte Carlo Estimation is that of approximating the value of $\pi$ :
We draw $n$ random points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and count how many points $m$ have norm (distance to origin) less than or equal to $1$. Since this represents the area of a quarter circle of radius $R=1$, the result should approach $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as $n\to\infty$, i.e. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{m}{n}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.
When implemented, this works well (although of course the convergence is incredibly slow). However, naively it does not seem necessary for the points to be chosen randomly - we could just cover the interval $I=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with points in a grid-fashion, which would "imitate" a random uniform distribution, especially for higher values of $n$.
However, that does not work : I used the code I wrote for the random case (which works), and just changed it so the points are spread uniformly on $I$. Even for very high values of $n$, e.g. $10^7$ or more, the result does not converge to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ but rather grows to infinity, it seems.
I am not sure why that happens, and would appreciate any insight. I am sharing the simple code snippets which I wrote if that helps.
This is the original random estimation function (using np for numpy):
def estimate_pi(num_points=1000):
    points = np.random.uniform(size=(num_points, 2))
    pts_inside_rad = points[np.where(np.linalg.norm(points, axis=1) <= 1.0)[0]]
    return 4 * pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points

This is the non-random function :
def estimate_pi(num_points=100):
    xs = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    points = np.array([[x, y] for x in xs for y in xs])
    pts_inside_rad = points[np.where(np.linalg.norm(points, axis=1) <= 1.0)[0]]
    return 4 * pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points

The random version works , tending to $\pi$ , while the non-random version seems not working , tending to $\infty$.

You should share the code !

@YvesDaoust: you are right. See my answer to myself.

@Prem: Also check out my answer to myself, it includes the code.

There is nothing wrong with asking questions when the math is not working out. I do not see why this is getting downvoted improperly. I will rectify with my +1.

Yeah, I also don't get - but this is the internet ¯\(ツ)/¯

For completeness, here's a simple python code using Monte Carlo:
import random
num_points = 100000
count = 0  
for _ in range(num_points):
  x = random.uniform(0, 1)
  y = random.uniform(0, 1)
  count += (x**2 + y**2) < 1
print(4*count/num_points)


So the answer is... I'm an idiot. I used $n$ to build a grid of $n^{2}$ points, but didn't change the calculation to be $\frac{m}{n^2}$. Now I did, and it works correctly. Thanks for all the answers!
FYI, this is the original random estimation function (using np for numpy):
def estimate_pi(num_points=1000):
    points = np.random.uniform(size=(num_points, 2))
    pts_inside_rad = points[np.where(np.linalg.norm(points, axis=1) <= 1.0)[0]]
    return 4 * pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points

...and this is the non-random function (fixed):
def estimate_pi(num_points=100):
    xs = np.linspace(0, 1, num_points)
    points = np.array([[x, y] for x in xs for y in xs])
    pts_inside_rad = points[np.where(np.linalg.norm(points, axis=1) <= 1.0)[0]]
    return 4 * pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points**2

The relevant fix was changing pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points to pts_inside_rad.shape[0] / num_points**2.
